# How to track Windows system calls

Tags: windows, kernel, system-calls

Is it possible to write a Windows 7 kernel module and create some generic system call filter? Simply, to write some code that is fired when a system call is made (from any process)?

Thanks
James

Comment: What Windows version? Generally it is possible but a lot of work. If you are interested only in particular details (files, registry) that will help to limit the effort required tremendously. On older versions SSDT hooking is a viable solution. On newer Windows versions you'll have to work around the kernel patch protection mechanism (which is possible, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great article on hooking Windows API [[1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx)]. It is a little old, and not covering Windows 7 kernel. But I think you can still borrow the idea somehow.